# Server 14.04 LTS and preventing Oculus as primary display

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, multiple-monitors, uefi

I have my game machine dual booted with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS UEFI.  I use the server edition because I use this as a continuous integration build node when otherwise not used for gaming.

Since it is used for gaming, the oculus is plugged in, in addition to a standard monitor.  I'd like to just pull the oculus from being a display possibility.  How would I go about doing that?  Will the suggested solution address the grub screen as well?

Comment: Could you please post your `monitors.xml` to http://paste.ubuntu.com and drop me a note @Fabby after you've done this?

Comment: @fabby there is no `monitors.xml` present on the file system.  As root, `find / -name monitors.xml` yielded no results, as did `find / -name monitor.xml`

Comment: Does going to system settings - screen display - detect displays -  apply - Keep this configuration generate one?

Comment: @Fabby - you are aware that this is the `server` version and I'm limited to the console?

Comment: Sorry!  Too many questions simultaneously...  You'll have to create the `monitors.xml`  from scratch using nano then...